# Bitcoin Core signing using signrawtransactionwithkey returns null

Tags: offline-transactions

I am trying to sign a transaction to spend funds from a 3 of 7 multisig address.

```
signrawtransactionwithkey 0200000001df84bf87bee6e5ef37252bee0aefffff01570400000000000017a914ab7810c333815366e268a8e21cdd516a73e353348700000000 "[   \"L19iWVPKJLUm316JUSwuKanZ1aUNk\",
    \"L4QXPc2ErXQ5cpmSizgnqL3VdUNFr3\",
    \"L3u2KCt3oBYp1rTn8a7AK8cdZjp8wsF\"
]" 
[{
    "txid": "a9d4599e15b53f3eb56bda871e8b34f2f430c",
    "vout": 0,
    "scriptPubKey": "a9142371a0f091d72061f52b3a87",
    "redeemScript": "53210386c5bb843616d7e504997778707701b5245904a48d0e2e7b64e0fe346bee975d321023bd5cef26304c25450933da1dd50d6d39625ae8154319e14884c76b0300336a22102ed48db7649ae65433f6c46bbdbf143927411c9c12878f85b64815183a458b5ea210379371734a424889ded7f8de018d7e4c6f1ce7196980c80e9d6f3bb748668415d2102051d068ac8dee4aa46af230ea46d96a860c4c65f000831e748b866ffdfb74f3d21029c7cc1f53494ae3ce3f44adbdf9bee34ce5f8e70cb099b9c72ba31f71cf1617c57ae",
    "amount": "0.00001234"
}]
```

Ive redacted a bit of the private keys, etc - though there are only a few sats so if someone guesses cracks it enjoy.

The response I am getting is "null" instead of the expected output from signrawtransaction (including the signed transaction).

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core are you using?

Comment: Maybe it is because a ton of things are wrong with your input. I'm not sure when you were "redacted" private keys you changed other things or not, but if you didn't they are wrong. More noticeably is your redeemScript which is 3 of 7 but provides only 6 public keys and also it has 1 extra bytes right after the first one (..975d**3**21023b..) which makes the hex and script invalid.